# Post object data in jquery to controller

Tags: jquery, vb.net

1. I tried run view and I have data in jquery
2. data is like=

> columnName:"blaName " , columnValue:"blaValue " columnName:"blaName "
>   ,
>          columnValue:"blaValue " columnName:"blaName " , columnValue:"blaValue "

but data didnt go controller ,Actually maybe data go I see data.lenght(**columnValue As `List(Of columnGrid)`) in controller

### but data is empty

My View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('body').on('keyup', '.search', function (event) {
            if (event.keyCode == 13) {

                var data = [];
                $('.search').each(function ()
                {
                    data.push({ columnName: $(this).attr('id'), columnValue: $(this).val()});
                });
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Home/PartialGrid',
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    cache: false,
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $(this).enabled = false;
                        $("#olur").html(data);

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
```

My Controller :

```
 Public Class columnGrid

        Public columnName As String
        Public columnValue As String
    End Class
    Function PartialGrid(columnValue As List(Of columnGrid)) As ActionResult
............
        Return PartialView(data)
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a root object like this:-

```
var data = [];
$('.search').each(function ()
{
    data.push({ columnName: $(this).attr('id'), columnValue: $(this).val()});
});
var dataTosend = { columnValue : data };
```

Please note I have defined `columnValue` here as the key for json object because at the server side you have defined the same variable. It should match.

Finally pass it to jquery ajax method like this:-

```
data: JSON.stringify(dataTosend ),
```

Comment: Function PartialGrid(columns As List(Of columnGrid)) As ActionResult

Comment: I change server columns and add var dataTosend = { columnValue : data }; but It isnt run .I see data count in action but inside nothing

Comment: and I try  "var dataTosend = { columns : data };" :)) but it doesnt run

Comment: @bgmm - Okay, the thing is variable name should be same at both place. What is not running? Any error you are getting? Please check browser console.

Comment: No I Have not any error only I cant get columns.there is columns count but is writed in columns columnName:nothing and columnValue:nothing 4 times

Comment: @bgmm - Then check your jQuery code, `$(this).attr('id')` by alerting if you are getting correct value at client side.

Comment: var data = [
                     { columnName: '1', columnValue: 'yellow'},
                     { columnName: '3', columnValue: 'red' },
                     { columnName: '2', columnValue: 'blue' },
                     { columnName: '4', columnValue: 'purple' },
            ];

          var dataTosend = { columns : data };
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/PartialGrid',
                data: JSON.stringify(dataTosend),
                cache: false,

Comment: I try for you , I write value myself, but ıt isnt please ıf you use mvc ,you try maybe I make anything

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

```
     $.ajax({
                        url: '/Home/PartialGrid',
                        data: JSON.stringify(data),
                        cache: false,
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        dataType: "html",
                        success: function (data) {
                            $(this).enabled = false;
                            $("#olur").html(data);

                        }
                    });




 Public Class columnGrid

            Public columnName As String
            Public columnValue As String
        End Class
        Function PartialGrid(data) As ActionResult
    ............// deserialize  your data here
            Return PartialView(data)
        End Function
```

because ajax post variable and it related method parameter must be same.

Comment: Function PartialGrid(data) As ActionResult
    ............// deserialize  your data here
            Return PartialView(data)

Comment: what is data type in action(PartialGrid(data As ???))? and How do I should deserialize? please you give me example, thanks

Comment: pass string data type

Comment: for eg: your serialize string as  "[{a},{b},{c}]"

Comment: you need create empty List class in controller as  public class ex{ public string a {get; set;}  public string b {get;set;}}

Comment: use javaScript serialize as

Comment: JavaScriptSerializer seralizer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

Comment: var result = seralizer.Deserialize<List<ex>>(data);

Comment: that all  use above code snippet one by one... it help to u

Comment: Function PartialGrid(data As String) As ActionResult      data is Nothing :(

Answer (score 0):

I update class code .Problem is only only (get set) method 
Thanks to all who responded to friends .

I add

script code 
 data = JSON.stringify({ 'columns': data });

```
  Public Class columnGrid

        Private _columnName As String
        Private _columnValue As String

        Public Property ColumnName As String
            Get
                Return _columnName
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                _columnName = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property ColumnValue As String
            Get
                Return _columnValue
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                _columnValue = value
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class
```